# Pentabromophenol Mass Spectrum

Tags: organic-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

I am working on analyzing the mass spectrum of pentabromophenol but am struggling to determine the fragment at 60 m/z. It could possibly be 5 carbons however that is too much positive charge to exist at high abundance.

Below are the mass spec retrieved experimentally and from literature.

Literature Mass spec: [NIST WebBook](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C608719&Units=SI&Mask=200#Mass-Spec)

Experimentally determined mass spectrum:
[image: Literature mass spec.]

Comment: Can you give a zoom-in of the region around 55 - 65 m/z?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to have the 1:1 $\ce{Br}$ ratio spaced by 1.

I think a reasonable assignment would be that it is $\ce{[BrCCOH]^2+}$

m = 120 and 122

m/z = 60 and 61